# sitecore ECM redirect url multiple websites

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-ecm

Sitecore 7.0
ECM - 2.1

I have a sitecore instance with multiple websites. I've installed ECM and I'm not sure what should I put in the Base Url field (/sitecore/content/Email Campaign). I've tried http://mywebsite1.com and it works. However for the other websites the url is something like http://mywebsite1.com/content/mywebsite2/page.
I'd like to have my urls to point directly to the website - http://mywebsite2/page. 
Should I have something different on my Base Url? Can I configure this configured somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only have one Base URL per ECM Manager root.

You could create a manager root under each site though which might meet your requirements. This is the recommended approach for a multi site EXM set up.

Take a look at the documentation on creating a manager root:

https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/30/setting_up_exm/the_manager_root/create_a_new_manager_root

Comment: Thats a good idea! But I'm not sure how can I configure sitecore to have multiple ecm manager root? I can add those items as per your recommendation but how ECM knows that for a X message should use the X ECM Manager root?

Comment: When you use the ECM SPEAK interface, on the dashboard screen, there should be an option in the top right to allow you to switch between ECM roots. You can then send a message for each site separately.Does that answer your question?

Comment: Did this help explain?

Comment: Ian it does help to explain but unfortunately I haven't been able to actually check it (I don't have access to it at the moment) but will definitely have a look soon and let you know if it worked. Thanks

Comment: Created a different ECM manager root and seems to be working. Thanks  @Ian Graham